# Repository Name as a GitHub Action environment variable?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

How would you get the repository name (not the user or organization) as an environment variable in GitHub Actions?
I found `github.repository` but that contains the owner as the first part like so: `owner/repo`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try `github.event.repository.name`

```yaml
- run: echo "REPO_NAME=${{ github.event.repository.name }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

---

[Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) aside, i'd *really* recommend dumping contexts (maybe in some test repo) just to get familiar with them, as there is lot of data which might or might not be useful when writing non-trivial workflows.

```yaml
- name: Dump github context
  run:   echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
  shell: bash
  env:
   GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
```

Be aware that parts of `github` context changes depends which event triggered workflow, so it might be a good idea to double check if data you want to use is available for all events used in workflow.

Comment: Thank you! For context, I needed this information for pull request events, I found the variable to be `github.event.pull_request.base.repo.name`. I am going to mark your post as the answer since its very good debugging advice and it lead me to the solution.

Comment: `github.event.repository.name` worked for me.

Comment: Might be useful to mention that `github.event.repository.name` is unavailable when your workflow is triggered on schedule.  Sorting through that right now!  :)

Comment: github.repository.name is not valid and does not contain the repository name. the rest of this answer is informative but the first example is simply invalid.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough! I would've saved so much time if I had known about `toJson(github)`...

Comment: Thank you for helping on this.

As the GH Actions grows and becomes more mature, this answer is no more actual.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75513916/10148424

Comment: `github.event.repository.name` is [now available when the workflow is triggered on schedule](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-27-github-actions-additional-information-available-in-github-event-payload-for-scheduled-workflow-runs/).

Answer (score 25):

I think the syntax you're looking for is actually `github.event.repository.name`

@Samira's `toJson(github)` tip was super useful. It took me a send look to notice the `repository` property was indented a bit further in, under `event.

You can use the value directly, or assign it at the top level with:

```
env:
  REPO_NAME: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
```

Answer (score 15):

example: https://github.com/maguowei/awesome-stars/blob/master/.github/workflows/schedules.yml#L21

```
- name: get epository name
  run: echo "REPOSITORY_NAME=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: This seems to be the most reliable way as `github.event...` doesn't work for scheduled triggers etc. This will always work

Comment: This works regardless of the event

Answer (score 4):

You can extract it from `github.repository`:

```
name: Print repo name

on:
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    print-name:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: get-name
              run: |
                  echo "REPO_NAME=$(basename ${{ github.repository }})" >> $GITHUB_ENV
            - name: print-name
              run: |
                  echo "${{ env.REPO_NAME }}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer has the advantage of working across all workflow events.

Answer (score 2):

#### Nowadays `${{ github.repository }}` more than enough.

If you need just the basename excluding repo owner or and other computed value, see example below.

##### **Please note!**

If you want to calculate some value, consider using [setting an output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) as it:

- more safe;
- more flexible when you'll switch to reusable actions, eg [Composite actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action).

Here's the complete and ready to go example for Vue app deploy to Github Pages:

```yaml
on:
  push:

jobs:
  pages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Pages Deploy
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Output setting example
    - id: repo-basename
      run: |
        echo "value=`basename ${{ github.repository }}`" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash

    - uses: xRealNeon/VuePagesAction@1.0.1
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Leave this line unchanged
        username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}

        # Using of computed variable example
        reponame: ${{ steps.repo-basename.outputs.value }}
```

Comment: For me, `${{ github.repository }}` gave me `myusername/my-repo-name` which was perfect!